# What is the history of the term "Alley-Oop"?

Tags: basketball, history, terminology

I realized I've been using the term for years but never realized that taken literally, it makes no sense.

"Alley" - other than the word alley, I have no idea what this could refer to.

"oop" - most likely a shortened version of hoop?

Is it a shortened version of another phrase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Alley-Oop" appears to have originated from the French term, "Allez Hop." "Allez Hop" is the "cry" made prior to the jumping of an acrobat in a circus<sub>[(1)](http://www.businessinsider.com/what-alley-oop-means-2014-2)</sub>.

"Alley-Oop" was used in the NFL during the 1950s with respect to the San Francisco 49ers, describing an arching pass in which taller receivers caught the ball over smaller defenders<sub>[(1)](http://www.businessinsider.com/what-alley-oop-means-2014-2)</sub>.

Though its origins were not etched in basketball, basketball adopted this term and is used today to describe a basketball player making a basket while catching the ball in mid-air<sub>[(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alley-oop_(basketball)#History)</sub>.

[image: Alley-Oop History]